# salesforce: How do I set custom tag homepage?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I've created custom object and custom tab (label text="order").

Now my header looks like below just like everyone can do.

```
[home]__[customer]__[order]
```

And when I click on `"order"` tab, I am redirected to home page of `"order"`

The "order" homepage has:

1. view (which goes to search feature)
2. recent record

My question is how do I change the layout of this homepage? I've look though entire site and documentations but seems like it is not possible. The only option I have is to create brand new visualforce page and set that page as default homepage for the "order" tab.

Comment: Pretty much yeah - if you want different layout you'd have to create your own Visualforce page. Maybe if you'd update your question with info how exactly you want to change the tab? What elements should be added/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change the contents of a default tab homepage beyond the limited controls under Setup. You would have to create a new Visualforce page and replace the page all together; however, with an enhancedList, you can get the basics down without too much coding, like this:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:enhancedList type="Account" height="500" />
</apex:page>
```

This would just show the standard Account list views on the tab (which could have Recent Items), but you could spruce things up with other components or make the list view customized with a set controller.